# okhttp post slower than get and why health check when not GET method

Tags: okhttp

in okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor

line 41: the origin code is:

`boolean doExtensiveHealthChecks = !request.method().equals("GET");`

when i compare the performance between OkHttp 3.4.1 and apache httpclient.

Get Method, OkHttp faster；

But the Post Method, OkHttp is more slower than httpclient's POST, always more slower than OkHttp's Get method.

Then debug the source code, and change the code like this:

```
boolean doExtensiveHealthChecks = false;
```

finally, OkHttp's POST method is faster than httpclient.

There question is， why doExtensiveHealthChecks when not "Get" method?

TKS.
First question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but GET is a safe Method, so it doesn't hurt to try, fail and then retry.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

For POST it makes sense to check the connection is healthy before attempting the request.